# Insert image in react-excel-workbook sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to insert the object image in the first column of this workbook sheet,

```
<Workbook.Sheet data={object.list} name="list">
    <Workbook.Column
         label={Strings.fields.image}
         value={(row: any) => this.getBase64Image(row.photo)}
    />
    <Workbook.Column
        label="Date"
        value={(row: any) =>
            row.date && DateTime.fromISO(row.date).toFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")}
    />
    <Workbook.Column label="Name" value="name" />
</Workbook.Sheet>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `react-excel-workbook` doesn't support images and other advance functionality. Because it's not built for this purpose. Secondly it's last publish on 4 years ago. That's why it's not well mentained.

In My opinion if you want the customization of excel sheet and advance functionality then you should you the `exceljs`. By default, It will provide you the Image Insert and other functionalities. You can check the methods related to images [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#images).